# What are the most comfortable endurance bib shorts these days?

Tags: road-bike, endurance

I generally ride for 30-70 miles each outing and am wanting to get a couple pairs of quality, comfortable bib shorts for summer weather. I tried on a couple Castellis but the fit just isn’t right and for one of their $200+ shorts, I would think they’d be more comfortable. The material seemed scratchy which obviously isn’t good for hours and miles in the saddle. I don’t mind spending extra as long as I’m getting top quality comfort, performance and durability.

Any recommendations are greatly appreciated. Thanks! Ride on!

Comment: We do not give product recommendations at this site. They quickly become obsolete and are often based on personal opinion which is often different for different people.

Comment: Regarding scratchiness: Get chamois cream, it’s a real eye-opener. Personally I haven’t found much difference between various bibs from Gore Bike Wear, Specialized, Scott or even cheap BBB. They all stretch out after some point and suddenly start rubbing (again, time for chamois cream to shine).

Answer (score 2):

This is completely dependent on your body dimensions (the exact shape of the relevant parts) and the exact way you sit and move your legs and the rest of the body. Everyone is different. There is no other way then to try riding in some bib shorts and see if they work well or not. That may even change if you get or loose some considerable amount of body fat or muscles in those areas.

Comment: Comfort can even depend on how you put the shorts on.  I remember seeing a MTB guy wearing road bibs like baggy shorts... that's not going to help !